# hashlib.md5 returns a weird object and indexing is also strange

Tags: python, byte, md5, hashlib

So I wanted to get to know how hashlib.md5 works and produced the following code:

```
import hashlib

a = b'yolo'

h = hashlib.md5(a).digest()
b = h[6:10]

print(h)
print(b)
```

Don't mind the fact that I used "yolo" as a string. This is just for testing.

Now when running this code, it produces

```
b'O\xde\xd1FG6\xe7xe\xdf#,\xbc\xb4\xcd\x19'
b'\xe7xe\xdf'
```

which quite frankly seems to be off. First of all, I expected 4 bytes (bytes 6-9 both included) to come out in the second line and the first part (the`\xe7xe`) is not even a byte (afaik).

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) says that I should get a bytes object from the call to `digest()`, but for some reason this seems to not be the case(?..). My understanding is that a bytes object is just a list of bytes (and the function should thus produce an output like `b'\x0f\xff\x75...'` or whatever and never produce an output containing `\xe7xe` or start with a letter). What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: When a byte is a printing ASCII character, it's shown as that character rather than with a hex escape. The 2nd byte is the ASCII code for `x`, the third byte is ASCII for `e`.

Comment: You're just misunderstanding how Python displays bytes objects. It really is a 4 byte string.

Comment: Try: `for c in b: print(hex(c))`

Comment: Also try `print(len(b))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b'\xe7xe\xdf'` is a `bytes` with exactly four bytes:

```
>>> [hex(b) for b in b'\xe7xe\xdf']
['0xe7', '0x78', '0x65', '0xdf']
```

It just-so-happens that two of those bytes fall in the ASCII printable range, so they're represented as characters instead of `\x##` sequences.

- `0x78` is `x`
- `0x65` is `e`

For confirmation, you can compare `b'\xe7\x78\x65\xdf'` with `b'\xe7xe\xdf'`. They're two different representations of the exact same bytes:

```
>>> b'\xe7\x78\x65\xdf' == b'\xe7xe\xdf'
True
```

For a more consistent human-readable representation, you can convert the `bytes` object to a hex string using it's [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) method:

```
>>> b'\xe7xe\xdf'.hex(' ')
'e7 78 65 df'
```

Or you can retrieve a hexstring from the get-go by using [`hash.hexdigest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) instead of [`hash.digest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest).

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to see just hex codes in representation then use [`.hexdigest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest) which will give you string

```
import hashlib
h = hashlib.md5(b'yolo').hexdigest()
print(h)  # 4fded1464736e77865df232cbcb4cd19
```

Keep in mind that now every byte is representing using 2 characters, so for example to get 3 first bytes you should do

```
print(h[:6])  # 4fded1
```